# TFS: Force copy a file that is in use

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, file-copying

So in my TFS build, after the compile, I'm trying to copy some dlls over to the server. If they're currently in use, the build will fail.

Is there a way to force the overwrite, even if the file is open?

Thanks!

Comment: If the file is being used by a process, you won't be able to overwrite it. You could kill the process using the file and overwrite it then. If its a Service that is using the file, you can stop the service, overwrite, and start the service back up in a batch file that is called from the TFS build.

Answer (score 0):

It's either a service or a desktop application accessing the dll file. You can find out what has access to the file using *handle.exe* from [SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals).

Once you know what is accessing the dll file you can stop/kill it.

Moreover, there are also many other ways which can bypass the system prompts. However, it seems no one fit your situation. More ways to achieve force copy for you reference: [How to copy "in use" files through batch file in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647701/how-to-copy-in-use-files-through-batch-file-in-windows-7)